# Proving the Babylonian Root Finding Method

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am trying to learn how I can prove that the Babylonian Root Finding method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots) will bring you closer and closer to the actual answer as the number of iterations increases.

For approximating the square root of some number $S$, the Babylonian method defines the "guess" at the $n+1$ iteration as:

$$x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n + S / x_n}{2}$$

Subtracting $√S$ from both sides gives:

$$ϵ_{n+1} = x_{n+1} - √S = \frac{x_n - √S + S / x_n - √S}{2} = \frac{ϵ_n + S - √S^2 - 2x_n√S + S}{2x_n}$$

Simplifying:

$$ϵ_{n+1} = \frac{ϵ_n}{2} - \frac{ϵ_n^2}{2√S}$$

This is where I get confused. I think what we need to do next is:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} ϵ_{n+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{ϵ_n}{2} - \frac{ϵ_n^2}{2√S}\right)$$

But I am still confused how the above statement would prove (e.g. why does the limit of $ϵ_{n}$ approach 0 for large $n$ ... while this is obvious, I don't see an $n$ term in the limit which allows me to conclude this ):

- The Babylonian method will get you the actual answer in infinite iterations?
- The result from the current iteration will be closer to the actual answer compared to the result at any previous iteration?
- The results from each successive iteration bring you closer at faster speeds to the actual answer?

Do we need to define $ϵ_{n+1} - ϵ_{n}$ in this proof? Do we need to use the Squeeze Theorem or the Monotone Sequence Theorem?

Thanks!

Comment: $\frac{x_n - √S + S / x_n - √S}{2} = \frac{ϵ_n + S - √S^2 - 2x_n√S + S}{2x_n}$ -- I doubt, pls explain

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to accept that $(x_n)_{n\geq 0}$ converges then the rest is simple, you start with,
$$ x_{n+1} = \tfrac{1}{2x_n}(x_n^2 + s) $$
Suppose your Babylonian sequence converges to limit $\ell$, then by taking the limit of both sides, you would get,
$$ \ell = \tfrac{1}{2\ell}(\ell^2 + s) $$
Now you can solve the equation for $\ell$ and find that $\ell = \sqrt{s}$.

So the more challenging question is how do you show that the limit exists? It is what you said, prove that $(x_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is a bounded sequence which is monotone.

Comment: @Nicholas: thank you for your kind answer!